# How can I send a message to @BotFather programmatically?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I know that a bot can be created in a telegram if you send the command `/newbot` to the bot `@BotFather`. But to do this, you need to take your device, open Telegram, open a chat with `@BotFather` and send him the command `/newbot`. Can all of the above be done programmatically?

P.S.: this is not laziness, but an attempt to optimize the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible to create such interaction with [mtproto](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto) libraries ([pyrogram](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram), [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon), [madelineproto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto), etc...)

Here is a PoC script using telethon (`python3 -m pip install -U telethon` first to install the dependency):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = ...
api_hash = "..."
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

BOT_NAME="..."
BOT_USER_NAME="..." # must end with -bot

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def message_handler(event):
    if 'Please choose a name for your bot' in event.raw_text:
        await event.reply(BOT_NAME)
    elif 'choose a username for your bot' in event.raw_text:
        await event.reply(BOT_USER_NAME)
    elif 'Done! Congratulations on your new bot' in event.raw_text:
        print("Bot created!")
        await client.disconnect()

async def main():
    await client.send_message('botfather', '/newbot')


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

You acquire the `app_id` and `app_hash` values from https://my.telegram.org/
and here is telethon's [doc](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Hi, is there a way to answer when bot father show options for you to select?

Comment: Hi, just in case anyone is looking for a way to answer bot father options, if you use `pyrogram` you should look for `Message.click()`

Comment: Well: "Please enter your phone (or bot token): ".

Comment: Ok, only the first time (I think), just specify phone number and choose a password to authorize the user.